# Not saving data for some reason after call to insertRowToIndexPath in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my app where I have the user add rows to the table.  I do this by calling "insertRowAtIndexPath":

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender {

    NSString *theObjectToInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row #: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.tableData count]];
    [self.tableData addObject:theObjectToInsert];
    NSLog(@"What is the count of the collection? %lu", self.tableData.count-1);
    NSIndexPath *newPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.tableData.count-1 inSection:0];
    [self.myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.myTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];


}
```

My problem that I've discovered is that after adding the necessary rows, I am not saving the data as I think I should.  Here is the method that is supposed to store the data:

```
- (void)saveAction {

    //I iterate through my entire UITableView to tally up the data from all of the rows
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [self.myTable numberOfSections]; ++j) {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.myTable numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i) {
            if ([self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]) {
                [cells addObject:[self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"The number of table rows are: %lu", (unsigned long)[cells count]);  

}
```

For some reason, this only prints out "4", even though I've added much more.  Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why would u save the UITableViewCell in the cells array? while u already have all the datas in the self.tableData array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would u save the `UITableViewCell` in the cells array? while u already have all the datas in the `self.tableData` array. Never store/access the UI object, just use the datamodel.

And coming to the point, from `UITableView` docs, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **returns nil if the cell is not visible**. So even though you have 10 cells, if only 4 cells are visible, then this method will return nil for the remaining 6 cells.

```
- (nullable __kindof UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;   
// returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range
```

Comment: I guess that is precisely my question.  In my table, there are fields that allows the user to enter data.  Is there a way for me to iterate through the table and collect all the data that the user has entered?

Comment: I don't think so, when the tableview scrolls, the data in the hidden cells will be lost. You can't access that unless you store the data in a model.

Comment: Or you can give different cell identifier for each cells, so that when you dequeue u will get the same cell. But even in that way u can't get the invisible rows

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the reverse, make a copy of your dataArray as table datasource, on the `addRow` then add it into the datasource array, reload table, when hit `save` then make the dataArray = dataArrayCopy, it will be much easier if you modify the datasource than the table itself

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  Can you show me what it is you want me to do?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Hi, well...im not sure i understand what u'r trying to do, but isnt u have already modify the data in your data array with `[self.tableData addObject:theObjectToInsert];` ? just call `[self.tableView reloadData];` instead of those lengthy inserting below that line?

If u want to get the number of cells, u cant because cell isnt visible is not counting, u have to count your datasource array `[self.tableData count]`

Comment: I guess that is precisely my question. In my table, there are fields that allows the user to enter data. Is there a way for me to iterate through the table and collect all the data that the user has entered?

Comment: Yes, u can update it dirrectly those field into your datasource array by the textfield delegate, after the user touched one textfield, get the cell's row value, and in 
`-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` u can update the datasource array object in real time as user enter, might got better way but this is easiest i think

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to find out how many rows have been created by far. I believe you must be using dequeueing feature of table views in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. This features allows only visible cells in memory and not all. So, even if you have 50 data sets in your model you will feel 50 cells existing but NO - at any point in time, you shall get only visible cells count. Key here is - **Cells which are not visible on screen are discarded by iOS.**

Your model count (`self.tableData.count`) is the right way to know how many cells you may have.